# mongodb - how to project last element of an array after an update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have the following query:

```
ListModel
    .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: list_id
        },
        {   
            $push: {
                "items": {
                    details: the_template
                }
            }
        },
        {
            new: true,
            projection: {
                items: 1
            }
        }
    )
```

So, this returns me the array of the updated document, but how would I get only the last element inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use of [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/), in your case :

---

```
ListModel
    .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: list_id,
        },
        {   
            $push: {
                items: {
                    details: the_template,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            new: true,

            projection: {
               items: {
                  $slice: -1,
               },
            },
        },
    );
```

Comment: Ah, i tried a variation of slice, which the an error. Will let you know once I've tried it out

Comment: okay, so it worked, but how would I only output the `items` field. Because right now, it returns the single element in an array, along with every other field

Comment: To not have the others fields, you gotta remove them one by one specifying `{ myField: 0, ... }`. If you want the result to be directly the value on the field, you gotta have to perform an `aggregate` request, which is way more difficult than a `projection`. I suggest you to just access the data like `res.items[0]`.

Comment: damn, no quick method. I'll just do the res.items then